# How to place the merged map to the bottom?

Tags: java, hashmap

After merging two maps I noticed that the last one is placed at the top when displaying the merged map :

```
Map<Integer, String> dataToSage = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
for(InterventionDTO i : list) {
    Map<Integer, String> data = interfaceSageService.getDataToSendToSAGEFromIntervPlanMP(i.getIdintervention());
    data.forEach((key, value) -> dataToSage.merge(key, value, (oldValue, newValue) -> {
        return newValue;
    }));
}
```

It gives an output of :

[image]

Although in the database the data is well ordered :

[image]

So how to place the last merged map at the bottom in the merge process ?

Comment: Even the database is not well ordered, even though you think it is. Unless you specify an order, the database is not required to return rows in any particular order. Although from a practical aspect it often does order output, this is due to a practical reason of being inserted in the right order means the rows are laid out on disk in that order, but there is no guarantee and it can change. btw, instead of the loop, you can just `dataToSage.putAll(data);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not assume any ordering when using `HashMap`.

If you need an ordering then you have two options:

1. If you want elements to be **sorted** based on ordering of keys, then you can use `TreeMap`. If you need other than natural ordering you can pass `Comparator` to the constructor.
2. If you want elements to be **ordered** based on their insertion order then you can use `LinkedHashMap`.